# Not homework, test review - help with determining valid subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

```
10) Determine which of the following sets is a subspace of Pn for an
    appropriate value of n.

EXPLAIN/PROVE WHY OTHERS ARE NOT VECTOR SPACES.

A: All polynomials of the form p(t) = a + bt2, where a and b are in R.
B: All polynomials of degree exactly 4, with real coefficients.
C: All polynomials of degree at most 4, with positive coefficients.


A) A only B) A and B C) B only D) C only
```

**The answer is A  (A only).**  ***WHY?***

1. I see that A is closed under scalar mult and vector addition, and
   includes the zero vector.
2. **But isn't B also closed unser scalar mult, vec addition, and inc. zero vector?**
3. **Am I correct that C is not a subspace because the positive coefficients make zero vector impossible?**

Test is on Monday; don't really have the opportunity to go to campus and ask my professor.

Comment: The polynomial $0$ is of degree $-\infty$, so it doesn't belong to the set of polynomials of degree exactly $4$

Comment: Nice question! Welcome to MSE:D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$B$ isn't closed under vector addition, and it doesn't include the zero vector. It only includes polynomials with degree exactly $4$. Let $f=x^4+1$ and let $g=-x^4$. Both are in $B$, but their sum is not, because it has degree $0$.

You're right about $C$. The restriction there also makes $C$ not closed under multiplication by the scalar $-1$.

Comment: Oh!  Thank you very much.  I have a better picture of how to view these problems.  I will accept your answer in 5 minutes.